# IntersectionObserver debouncer

Tags: javascript, optimization, lazy-loading

I'm using the [IntersectionObserver polyfill](https://github.com/linkedin/spaniel) to lazyload images on tiles. 
The problem is I have a few thousand tiles each one with a image on it that needs to be lazyloaded.

Previously I used a scroll debouncer to load the image only when the scroll stops which was gave huge improvement in performance.

The question is how to use a scroll debouncer together with IntersectionObserver?

One solution but a stupid one is to create a preliminary array of visible items and add a timeout

```
 let timeoutLastEntities;

 new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
     setTimeout(function(){ 
        timeoutLastEntities.add(entities);
      }, 3000);
      // debouncer logic
 }, { threshold: 0.5 }).observe(imageTileElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a recipe but it's still not fitting perfectly

```
private initializeLazyLoader() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        this.processLazyChanges,
        { threshold: [0.5] }
    );

    // When scroll is triggered
    this.registerIntersectionObserverEvent(this.nativeElement, 'scroll', 300);
}

processLazyChanges(changes: any) {
    changes.forEach((change: any) => {
        var container = change.target;
        $(container).css('border', '1px solid red');
        this.observer.unobserve(container);
    });
}

private registerIntersectionObserverEvent(element: any, event: any, debouncerTime: number) {
    Observable.fromEvent(element, event)
        .debounceTime(debouncerTime)
        .subscribe((event) => this.initializeObservers(event));
}

private initializeObservers(event: any) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('app-tile')).forEach((tile: any) => {
        this.observer.observe(tile);
    });
}
```